# PyLab: Plotting axes to log scale, but labelling specific points on the axes

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

Basically, I'm doing scalability analysis, so I'm working with numbers like 2,4,8,16,32... etc and the only way graphs look rational is using a log scale.

But instead of the usual 10^1, 10^2, etc labelling, I want to have these datapoints (2,4,8...) indicated on the axes

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it, depending on how flexible/fancy you want to be.

The simplest way is just to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.exp2(np.arange(10))

plt.semilogy(x)
plt.yticks(x, x)

# Turn y-axis minor ticks off 
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_locator(mpl.ticker.NullLocator())

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to do it in a more flexible manner, then perhaps you might use something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.exp2(np.arange(10))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
ax.semilogy(x)
ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().base(2)
ax.yaxis.get_minor_locator().base(2)

# This will place 1 minor tick halfway (in linear space) between major ticks
# (in general, use np.linspace(1, 2.0001, numticks-2))
ax.yaxis.get_minor_locator().subs([1.5])

ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().base(2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.exp2(np.arange(10))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
ax.semilogy(x)
ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().base(2)
ax.yaxis.get_minor_locator().base(2)

ax.yaxis.get_minor_locator().subs([1.5])

# This is the only difference from the last snippet, uses "regular" numbers.
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image]